# How to this run as javascript function

Tags: javascript

I have having trouble with the code below; I cant make it run in a JavaScript function. This just shows a toast message at the top of the page. The below code just runs on pageLoad and works fine. But when I am putting it in a function it doesn't work and produces this error:

> Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#gritter-error').on(ace.click_event, function(){
                $.gritter.add({
                    title: 'This is a warning notification',
                    text: 'Just add a "gritter-light" class_name to your $.gritter.add or globally to $.gritter.options.class_name',
                    class_name: 'gritter-error' + (!$('#gritter-light').get(0).checked ? ' gritter-light' : '')
                });
                return false;
            });
})
```

Comment: _"but when I am putting it in a function it dosen't work"_ Please show how you are putting it in a function.

Comment: function callIt() {
         
    }pasting the code in it

Comment: if you know the right way please share it with me. Thank you

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65591241/edit) to show your exact code.

Comment: This code is from ace-master UI Template. All I need to do is to call this in a javascript function in a button onClick event. that is all... this code runs fine when reloading page

Comment: Code Edited. when i click the button with id "gritter-error" it works. now how to call it in a javascript function???? thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
function test(){
  $.gritter.add({
    title: 'This is a warning notification',
    text: 'Just add a "gritter-light" class_name to your $.gritter.add or globally to $.gritter.options.class_name',
    class_name: 'gritter-error' + (!$('#gritter-light').get(0).checked ? ' gritter-light' : '')
  });
}
```

and call this function in javascript where you want

Comment: Your function just works fine when i call it like this, onload = test(); but if i use it in button onClick it gives this error "Cannot read property 'add' of undefined at test"

Comment: $(document).on('click','.button_id', function(){test()});